# Python : to add serial number in a text file and header

Tags: python

I am a python noob ,imagine i have a .txt file which contains

```
123456789    1234    apple\wasdsa\sgfgf\sgf\rgfd.csv
124555669    6547    mango\sdf\hjt\sthsdth\eth.txt
564984565    58475   ksfjk\hjkf\tkohj\fdgs.opp
```

and the list continues.But i need it to format it like this with the header and with the serial numbers which will keep on increment according to the number of lines :

```
Sr.no.  MD5          Size    Path
1       123456789    1234    apple\wasdsa\sgfgf\sgf\rgfd.csv
2       124555669    6547    mango\sdf\hjt\sthsdth\eth.txt
3       564984565    58475   ksfjk\hjkf\tkohj\fdgs.opp
```

I am not able to overwrite it on the same .txt file , and also i am not able to generate the serial number. Please help me.

Comment: And save the output into another file or just print the output?

Comment: well, a way to solve the problem would be reading line after line and putting each line as a set/subarray (with index) into an array till you're done reading. Then overwriting the file.

Comment: well i want to overwrite it on the same text file @andreis11

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow.
This isn't a free code writing service.
Neither is it a replacement for tutorials or web searches.
Please read [ask]. Then [edit] your question and add the code you've tried so far. What happens when you run it? What did you expect to happen instead? Any errors?
If you don't know where to start coding, do a web search and read some tutorials first. 
Good luck!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use

```
data = """
123456789    1234    test123
124555669    6547    test456
564984565    58475   test789
"""

header = "Sr.no.  MD5          Size    Path\n"

output = header + "\n".join(
    "{}\t{}".format(line_number, line)
    for line_number, line in enumerate(
        (item for item in data.split("\n") if item), 1))
print(output)
```

Which would yield

```
Sr.no.  MD5          Size    Path
1       123456789    1234    test123
2       124555669    6547    test456
3       564984565    58475   test789
```

Question is if these escaped characters are really in the actual string?

Comment: how can i add a full .txt file in that code ?, I am dealing with a .txt file.